# TableRow column alignemnts

Tags: android, tablerow

I have a table row that looks like this:

```
<TableRow>
  <TextView />       //Weight:.30 - right align
  <ImageView />      //Weight:.10 - right align
  <TextView />       //Weight:.20 - MUST BE ABSOLUTE CENTRE
  <ImageView />      //Weight:.10 - left align
  <TextView />       //Weight:.30 - left align
</TableRow>
```

Based on the above sample, how can i assure that the TextView column is ALWAYS absolute center, and the rest of the items stacked to the right, and to the left of it?

Comment: Can you show the real layout? The TableView declaration and rows inside.

Comment: the only thing not visible here is `<TableLayout>` which wraps the TableRow. For some reason the editor does not want me to add it.